# how to manually fix npm vulnerabilities?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules, package-lock.json

When I'm trying to run 'npm update' I get 31 vulnerabilities. 'npm audit fix' and 'npm audit fix --force'. Do not seem to help. I think I need to manually update the vulnerabilities. But how do I do this?

A piece of of the output after running 'npm audit' shows this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA6Ul.png)

I've also tried to do "npm update [package]" on the packages that are indicated in the npm audit report. But everything is already up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: npm audit fix]

By `npm audit fix` you get packages with vulnerabilities or packages that use other packages that has vulnerabilities.

- You can simply read audit packages:

`strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0 Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex`

- You can update or downgrade that package as your requirements,
  [npm official site](https://www.npmjs.com/)
- You can search about that package , theirs all kind of information about package

By the way, there is a saying that "**don't fix a code if it's Running fine**"